# Bounded, tight sets of measures are compact?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In Prokhorov's 1956 paper "Convergence of Random Processes..." it states the following.

[image]

Where $\mathcal{R}$ is a complete, separable, metric space.

Additionally, it says that any weakly convergent sequence of measures satisfies conditions 1,2. This would give that any sequence is compact.

Isn't a counterexample to this the set of Dirac probability measures $\delta_{(1/n)}$ for $n\geq1$ on $\mathbb{R}$? Every element in the sequence has measure 1, and the set $[-2,2]$ is a compact set giving the tightness bound, but the limit $\delta_{(0)}$ is not in the sequence.

This seems to be in contradiction to results stated elsewhere, e.g. (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140760/prokhorovs-theorem-for-finite-signed-measures).

Should it be the case that it should say relatively compact instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, he means the set of measures $\mathfrak N$ is relatively compact if the two conditions are met.  I don't have access to the Russian original, so cannot tell if the mistake is Prohorov's or his translator's.